# Why Shouldn't I Change a Global Variable Inside a Function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I am writing JavaScript code and was told that I should not change a global variable within a function. Why would this be a problem? Are there any standard alternatives to this?

Comment: It's a matter of risk management. That global variable could affect something else without the intent of affecting anything else.

Comment: You should use as few global variables as possible, but if it useful to your code and you cannot think of another way to achieve it, you can do it.

Comment: @Joe So it would be better to create a new variable? e.g. test2=test and then alter test2 as needed?

Comment: @jcoat It is absolutely useless to assign a variable if the side-effect result is not desired. If it is desired, then the assignment *must* be done.

Comment: @jcoat Every situation is different, it's about the design of your application, there's not a single solution for every situation. Show what code you would like to remove globals from.

Comment: @JuanMendes I already removed the global. I'm just now trying to understand the principle behind why I did it.

Comment: @pst The problem of variables being clobbered is not as important in my opinion because it can easily be solved by namespacing. However, the problem of unwanted side effects (spaghetti code) is much harder to remedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any language, changing a global variable from a function usually makes the the function's output not deterministic, which makes following the code hard and often causes unwanted side effects. Therefore, you should avoid it if you can by properly scoping your variables, hard to help without seeing the code

Name clobbering is also an issue. However, that can easily be remedied by namespacing your globals.

Lastly, as you probably know since your question does say "why shouldn't I change a global variable", readonly globals (constants) aren't really a problem because they don't change and therefore don't have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

[See this Cartoon](http://www.datamation.com/imagesvr_ce/3549/global-variable.jpg)

Global variables are the anti-thesis of thread-safe systems. You should not have them, but if you have them, only one thread should own/change them. They should always be dealt with through a service layer.

Comment: Could you define thread?